# Large space between texts after inserting a wrapfigure

Tags: spacing, formatting, line-breaking

I am currently having a problem with using latex, as when I insert a wrapfigure, some of my text gets extended. For example, it becomes like this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Edit:

```
\[ x_{new} =  h_{\theta1}(x_j - x_i, \|x_j - x_i\|_2)) \tag{6} \label{equ:6}\]
where $x_j - x_i$ and $\|x_j - x_i\|_2$ xxx xxxxx xxxxxs and the xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx and $h_{\theta1}$, $h_{\theta2}$ and $h_{\theta3}$ are mxxxxx\cite{mish} xxxxxxxx. xxxxxx constructing xxxxxx xxxxx, each local xxxxxt and xxxxx feature are fed into xxxxx xxxxx, to lift xxxxx xxxxxx into the xxxx xxxx of channels to carry same xxxxxxx when xxxxxx. 
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2.2in}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=0.8in]{idis.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Visualization of sub-sampled points using DRS} \label{fig:4}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code that produces this? It is hard to debug only seeing some screenshot of a single line... Maybe the word in the next line wasn't correctly hyphenated because it's in an `\mbox` or similar. Or do you have any `\linebreak` there? Possibilities are many here.

Comment: that is not directly related to wrapfig other than that makes the lines narrower so it is harder to justify the text, the justification depends on the entire paragraph so it's not possible to really suggest anything without seeing the rest of that text you may need to add explicit hyphenation to some words, or use sloppypar so that the white space is spread more evenly over the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have added a code sample and the image again. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I can't reproduce your spacing with the code you provided if I just put `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}` around it and load the necessary packages. Can you please make sure that your example code can be compiled as is and actually shows the issue you're facing? To be clear, it should contain everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` to produce a small example.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The problem has been solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `wrapfig` documentation:

> It is convenient to begin the environment between paragraphs, but if you want placement in the middle of a paragraph, you must put the environment between two words where there is a natural line break.

In your code you are writing the `wrapfigure` right after the text, and TeX will stretch the line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\centering\fboxsep5pt\fbox{Something}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As the documentation suggest, you should better place the environment between paragraphs, e.g. you should leave an empty line before `wrapfigure` in your code.

Comment: Thank you, it works now!